# Meteor document ID is rendered with garbage characters

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I inserted a collection into MongoDB with a Python script. A typical document looks like this:

```
{       _id: { _str: '571eae67ab2c0d18c8509d0f' },
  something: '6.10',
       area: '1805.80'}
```

In the Python script, **id was not set explicitly**, this `_id` is what MongoDB has generated.

Now this `_id` is rendered in templates like this:

```
 571eae67ab2c0d18c8509d0f""{}
```

And in URLs as well. So when I open `/record/571eae67ab2c0d18c8509d0f""{}`, the findOne function queries `{_id: '571eae67ab2c0d18c8509d0f""{}'}` and finds nothing.

What should I fix in this scheme?

I looked up other questions here, and tried this:

```
= this._id.toHexString
= _id.toHexString
= _id._str
```

But it outputs nothing.

Comment: Did you specify the `idGeneration: 'MONGO'` option when creating the Mongo collection (in Meteor)?  Is there a mix of string and ObjectID `_id`s? If the ids have no significance (i.e, are not referenced anywhere etc.), consider replacing them with strings.

Comment: @MasterAM no, I didn't. And `_id`s are the same in the collection. I also tried this: entered Mongo shell, got an object, deleted the `_id` and  reinserted it. The new `_id` was of the same kind, with `_str` prop.

Comment: That is because MongoDB will automatically generate an `ObjectId`. You should explicitly specify an `_id` to prevent this behavior. If your `_id`s in this collection will always be `ObjectID`s, you can specify this to Meteor as I mentioned in the previous comment. If you want them to be strings, you can try to do a one-off conversion using Meteor and change your Python routine to generate string ids.

Comment: After setting idGeneration to 'MONGO', reinserting objects, I see no change. Search works like this: `a = Houses.findOne({_id: new Mongo.Collection.ObjectID('f611d70ca6c92c213f7fff83')})`

Comment: @MasterAM looks like it is EasySearch that converts ObjectID into string this way, because `this` in template has a flat `_id` string and an additional `_originalid` property.

Comment: oh :( I knew I recognized this pattern from somewhere. Didn't use easy-search in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a helper and debug output I found out that the `_id` did not contain any kind of object id, but a string. The problem was with [EasySearch](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search) that flatterns the `_id` for its own purposes.

Here's a description: https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/issues/347#issuecomment-152793656

> I'm experiencing a problem where the search query is added to end the of all the id's.
>   When there is nothing in the input box, it's just adds an empty "" at the end of id
>
> [image]
>
> And if there is any input, it gets inserted inside the quotation marks.
>
> [image]

Answer:

> Ran into the same "issue" yesterday, it turns out you should use _originalId as the doc says :
>
> > EasySearch returns documents when using search that have the same fields as the original ones, but the _id is different. If you want to perform changes on search result documents by the id you can use the __originalId which contains the original _id of the document. So collection.findOne(doc._id) won't work, while collection.findOne(doc.__originalId) would.
> >     The search-appended _id is probably used internally by this package